# Pushing Function Array into ;Another Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am developing a recipe website in which I am using an API to pull in ingredients and nutritional information. On my site, I am wanting to have a person search to add ingredients from this and only this list. I'm pretty green with javascript, so this likely is user error. What I've found so far is this:

```
const api_url = `https://reqres.in/api/users`;
const matchList = document.getElementById('results');

function getData(){
    fetch(api_url).then(response =>{
        return response.json();
    }).then(data =>{
        const html = data.data.map(user =>{
            return `"${user.first_name}"`
        }).join(',');
        console.log(html);
    });
};

let suggestions = [
    "Taco",
];
```

I'm needing the "let suggestions = []" for a different piece of code, but I'm unable to capture the array that is found in the getData() function. Any thoughts on how to go about this?

Comment: What does a `users` API have to do with recipes and ingredients?

Comment: Hello - the users API is similar in setup (but with significantly less data). So I felt it easier to code to this API first before calling on the real dataset.